# How do I make CSS tell elements to appear over one another?

Tags: css

I am very new at this, so I apologize for the slightly vague question. But here is all the information. I am working on a "website" for school. I would like my lay out to appear as a menu type thing on the left side with two different buttons on the right side, appearing one over the other. I have attached an image, just in case this makes no sense. When I `float:right`, it gets it close to where I want it to be, but not exactly. The elements  end up appearing in the lower right hand corner. How do I get them to do what I want them to do? the element layout
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rynmt.png)
[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKGUJ.png)

Comment: position:absolute for the one you want to overlay

Comment: use `position:absolute` and also use `z-index` to specify which one is on the top of the other

Comment: It would be nice if you can insert your codes from your software into a jsfiddle and put the link in the question or just put the codes in your question...by doing this someone can troubleshoot the issue easily instead of re-creating your scenario based on an a picture....see stackoverflow help link http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve good luck (no downvote from me, just a suggestion)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understood correctly, but when you say one over the other one I think you trying to say one on top of the another.

Let me know If I'm on the right way :)

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5x8740po/2/).

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="left-sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>home</li>
      <li>about</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="box">
      <p>This is a box</p>
    </div>
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {height: 100%;}
#left-sidebar {
  width: 120px;
  height: 400px; 
  float: left; 
  background: red; 
}
ul { margin-top: 20px; color: white;}
#main {
  width: calc(100% - 120px);
  height: 400px; 
  background: green;
  float: left;
 }
#box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
}
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

I hope this helps.